# About the cameras in the original Metal Gear Solid for PSX

Tags: camera

Since I first played MGS on the PSX I have been wondering about this.

To my understanding, MGS loads the geometry of the 'room' where you are and lets you move through it by using semi-fixed cameras that can follow you to a certain degree until your character gets in the range of another camera, and then seems to transition from the last angle of the previous camera to the initial angle of the current camera.

However, since this game does not seem to have a great deal of reverse engineering done, I wonder if anybody has replicated this scheme on any game (stealth or not) to study it.

As far as I know, the only one I have found with a similar approach is Resident Evil Code: Veronica, which switched from pre-rendered backgrounds to 3D but restricted the cameras available, as in the previous installments, giving the cameras certain degree of freedom in following the player (but less than MGS since RECV is about being afraid, not being stealthy).

I know I am asking a questio too broad and risk to be tagged as such... but it's been a lot of time since MGS got out and I still wonder about if anybody has more concrete answers to my guess about how MGS works.

Comment: Answering questions of historical curiosity isn't something we do here. Instead, we're focused on helping game developers solve problems in the games they're building today. Are you working on implementing a similar semi-fixed camera system in your current game project, and need some insights to help you with that feature? If so, try editing your question to ask about *your game*. "How can I achieve camera behaviour similar to game X" is on-topic here, while "How did game X achieve their camera behaviour" is not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about developing a new game or game mod. If that is inaccurate, please edit your question to explain the context of the game or mod you are making.

Comment: I am indeed developing a 3D prototype to show to investors, but I understand the question is too broad.

Comment: Want to edit your question to ask about your prototype instead? Walk us through how you've tried implementing your camera so far, what parts are working as desired, and what problem you need help solving. Then we can re-open that more focused question.